# selenium webdriver actionchains not working as expected

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using action chain to drop down in selenium webdriver, here is my code, can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong. I'm not using the page object pattern this time, so there is no "self" argument here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from behave import given, when, then
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


@given('Open RF page')
def open_website(context):
    context.driver.get('https://www.raymourflanigan.com/')


@when('Select Living Room')
def select_living_room(context):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    menu = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a")
    sofa = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")
    actions.move_to_element(menu).move_to_element(sofa).click()


@then("Verify {product} are available")
def verify(context, product):
    result = context.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.Category_Bnr_Title").text
    assert 'Sofas & Couches' in result,  f"Expected text is:  {result}."
```

Also, I removed `perform()`, because for some reason the second function isn't working with `perform()` in it. Seems like it does not work properly without it either, so if anyone knows why and can help me, it'll be great! I am just learning) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, but nothing too big. Seems all changes need to be done in `select_living_room`.

- `select_living_room` is taking a `context` object in it's arguments, but then the first thing it does is create a whole new `webDriver`. But **then** it accesses a *completely different* `webDriver` that is a member of `context`. I am guessing you are trying to do one of these:

  1. accept `context`, which has a driver already included. If that is the case, get rid of this: `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
  2. create a *new* driver as an attribute of `context`. In that case, change to this: `context.driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
- In either case, I don't see anywhere where `get` is being called on the driver to open the page. In `select_living_room` it is necesary to call `open_website`.
- The `ActionChain` is not running. Need to add a `perform()` call on the end.

I change `select_living_room` to work like this (assumes that the `webDriver` is already set up inside of `context`):

```
@when('Select Living Room')
def select_living_room(context):
    open_website(context)
    menu = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a")
    sofa = context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")
    actions = ActionChains(context.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(menu).move_to_element(sofa).click().perform()
```

Then running like this works:

```
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ctx = Context(webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver', options=opts))
select_living_room(ctx)
verify(ctx, None)
```

Note that you don't mention what `Context` is. I stubbed it out:

```
class Context:
  def __init__(self, ctx):
    self.driver = ctx
```